# How can I unit test Log4j using JMockIt?

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, log4j, jmockit

When a Logger (Or any static field) is declared in a class using a static method:

```
public class Foo {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Foo.getClass);
}
```

**What is the correct way in which I can assert that methods on it are called (for auditing)?**

The following *will work*, but setField appears to be the wrong way to go about it, nullifying the use of the @Tested annotation to allow automatic injection.

```
@Mocked Logger logger
new Expectations() {
  {
    setField(unitUnderTest, logger);
  }
}
```

JMockIt seems to provide a solution with *@UsingMocksAndStubs(Log4jMocks.class)*, however this does not allow Expectations on it as it causes calls to getLogger() to return a real, but useless, Logger rather than a mocked instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple:

```
@Test
public void verifyAuditing(@Cascading final Logger logging)
{
    // Call code under test which will create auditing records.

    new Verifications() {{ logging.info("expected audit info"); }};
}
```

The use of `@Cascading` causes `Logger` to be mocked in "cascading" mode, where every method which returns a reference type automatically creates a mocked instance. The initial mocked instance `logging` represents all such instances.

Comment: Fantastic! This does exactly what I needed, I seem to have misunderstood what @Cascading did. Thanks.

Comment: @ Rogério: Cascading mocks the returned value of a method call automatically, but what does it have to do with your test?  There's nothing to mock because logging.info has no return type.  I ask because this helped solve a similar problem of mine using Logger, but I don't understand why Mocked wouldn't work just as well.

Comment: @WillLovett The code under test calls `Logger.getLogger(...)`, which then returns a cascaded `Logger` instance. This is what cascading is for here; it's not for the `info(...)` call. BTW, in recent versions of JMockit, cascading became default on all mocked objects, and @Cascading was removed.

Comment: Looks like @Cascading is now deprecated in the latest JMockit. Any alternatives?

Comment: @supertonsky Just use `@Mocked` instead, it cascades as well.

Comment: It may cascade, but it does not capture. The OP asked for Log4J, which I do not know about, but at least for Slf4J/Logback you need `@Capturing`.

Answer (score 1):

This question and answer describes what I hoped to do so perfectly, yet I found no joy in my attempt to implement the answer accepted here--tried hard to make it work but maybe my configuration is different in some significant way?? So, in case it will help anyone else, I'll offer this admittedly batsh!t-crazy alternative that does have the advantage of actually working for me (Java6, JMockit 1.7, JUnit 4.8.1, SLF4J 1.5.10).

The general strategy was to implement a slf4j Logger which will delegate to a mock logger. This combination seemed to allow me to get everything wired up right in a way that was totally non-invasive to the system under test. In the system under test, I have:

```
private static Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(SUT.class);
```

And, of course, various usages of log..

In my test class..

```
private static final TestLogger log = new TestLogger();

@Mocked
private Logger mockLogger;

@Tested
SUT sut = new SUT();

@BeforeClass
public static void replaceLogger() {
    new MockUp<LoggerFactory>() {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Mock
        Logger getLogger(Class clazz) {
            return log;
        }
    };
}

@Before
public void setup() {
    // go ahead and prefix this with name of test class, since log is static..
    log.setLogger(mockLogger);
}

@Test
public void ensure_some_behavior_happens() {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        ...
    }};

    sut.someMethodOfInterest();

    new Verifications() {{
        mockLogger.warn("expected logging"); maxTimes = 1;
    }};
}
```

Ok the crazy part now--eclipse helped quite a bit, but still a major pain to implement Logger. Really made me appreciate the Interface Segregation Principle.

```
public class TestLogger implements Logger {
    Logger l = null;
    public void setLogger(Logger log) { l = log; }
    public String getName() { return l != null ? l.getName() : ""; }
    public boolean isTraceEnabled() { return l != null ? l.isTraceEnabled() : false; }
    public void trace(String msg) { if (l != null) l.trace(msg); }
    public void trace(String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.trace(format, arg); }
    public void trace(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.trace(format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void trace(String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.trace(format, argArray); }
    public void trace(String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.trace(msg, t); }
    public boolean isTraceEnabled(Marker marker) { return l != null ? l.isTraceEnabled(marker) : false; }
    public void trace(Marker marker, String msg) { if (l != null) l.trace(marker, msg); }
    public void trace(Marker marker, String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.trace(marker, format, arg); }
    public void trace(Marker marker, String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.trace(marker, format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void trace(Marker marker, String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.trace(marker, format, argArray); }
    public void trace(Marker marker, String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.trace(marker, msg, t); }
    public boolean isDebugEnabled() { return l != null ? l.isDebugEnabled() : false; }
    public void debug(String msg) { if (l != null) l.debug(msg); }
    public void debug(String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.debug(format, arg); }
    public void debug(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.debug(format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void debug(String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.debug(format, argArray); }
    public void debug(String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.debug(msg, t); }
    public boolean isDebugEnabled(Marker marker) { return l != null ? l.isDebugEnabled(marker) : false; }
    public void debug(Marker marker, String msg) { if (l != null) l.debug(marker, msg); }
    public void debug(Marker marker, String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.debug(marker, format, arg); }
    public void debug(Marker marker, String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.debug(marker, format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void debug(Marker marker, String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.debug(marker, format, argArray); }
    public void debug(Marker marker, String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.debug(marker, msg, t); }
    public boolean isInfoEnabled() { return l != null ? l.isInfoEnabled() : false; }
    public void info(String msg) { if (l != null) l.info(msg); }
    public void info(String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.info(format, arg); }
    public void info(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.info(format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void info(String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.info(format, argArray); }
    public void info(String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.info(msg, t); }
    public boolean isInfoEnabled(Marker marker) { return l != null ? l.isInfoEnabled(marker) : false; }
    public void info(Marker marker, String msg) { if (l != null) l.info(marker, msg); }
    public void info(Marker marker, String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.info(marker, format, arg); }
    public void info(Marker marker, String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.info(marker, format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void info(Marker marker, String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.info(marker, format, argArray); }
    public void info(Marker marker, String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.info(marker, msg, t); }
    public boolean isWarnEnabled() { return l != null ? l.isWarnEnabled() : false; }
    public void warn(String msg) { if (l != null) l.warn(msg); }
    public void warn(String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.warn(format, arg); }
    public void warn(String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.warn(format, argArray); }
    public void warn(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.warn(format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void warn(String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.warn(msg, t); }
    public boolean isWarnEnabled(Marker marker) { return l != null ? l.isWarnEnabled(marker) : false; }
    public void warn(Marker marker, String msg) { if (l != null) l.warn(marker, msg); }
    public void warn(Marker marker, String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.warn(marker, format, arg); }
    public void warn(Marker marker, String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.warn(marker, format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void warn(Marker marker, String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.warn(marker, format, argArray); }
    public void warn(Marker marker, String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.warn(marker, msg, t); }
    public boolean isErrorEnabled() { return l != null ? l.isErrorEnabled() : false; }
    public void error(String msg) { if (l != null) l.error(msg); }
    public void error(String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.error(format, arg); }
    public void error(String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.error(format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void error(String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.error(format, argArray); }
    public void error(String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.error(msg, t); }
    public boolean isErrorEnabled(Marker marker) { return l != null ? l.isErrorEnabled(marker) : false; }
    public void error(Marker marker, String msg) { if (l != null) l.error(marker, msg); }
    public void error(Marker marker, String format, Object arg) { if (l != null) l.error(marker, format, arg); }
    public void error(Marker marker, String format, Object arg1, Object arg2) { if (l != null) l.error(marker, format, arg1, arg2); }
    public void error(Marker marker, String format, Object[] argArray) { if (l != null) l.error(marker, format, argArray); }
    public void error(Marker marker, String msg, Throwable t) { if (l != null) l.error(marker, msg, t); }
}
```

Anyway, I would definitely see if the one of the other solutions works first, but if you should get desperate, maybe give this approach a try.

**EDIT:** Ok..I'm feeling altogether better about this approach after I turned the TestLogger above into a dynamic proxy implementation. Here's how to go with that..

First, give yourself an interface..

```
public interface TestLogger extends Logger {
    void setLogger(org.slf4j.Logger wrapped);
}
```

Then you'll need an invocation handler..

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class TestLoggerInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Logger wrapped;

    private TestLoggerInvocationHandler() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if ("setLogger".equals(method.getName())) {
            wrapped = (Logger)args[0];
            return null;
        }
        return wrapped != null ? method.invoke(wrapped, args) : null;
    }

    public static TestLogger createTestLogger() {
        return (TestLogger) (Proxy.newProxyInstance(TestLogger.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { TestLogger.class }, new TestLoggerInvocationHandler()));
    }

}
```

Just call the static factory method in the test class and you should be good to go--not so crazy after all!

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the field non-static, with Logger.getLogger(...) as default, and then provide a setter to inject the mocked logger. If you have the Test in the same package as the original class, you can at least declare the setter package-protected.

As far as I know, getLogger would always return the same logging instance, so even if you have hundreds of instances of your class, you don't have hundreds of Loggers around.

Comment: I would imagine the field could remain `static`, provided you have a setter; it just cannot be `final`. How does your final paragraph relate to the question?

Comment: In general, I don't suggest to keep it static, as you then could get intro troubles if other unit tests rely on the logger to be the original Logger.

Comment: And in case you don't keep it static, my last paragraph explains why it is save to remove the static keyword without flooding your memory with hundreds Logger instances.